# How do I get a button inside a React-Bootstrap Navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

So apparently you can't put DOM elements inside the React-Bootstrap Navbar. I want to add a Login button to my site's header. The header is made up of my logo and a React-Bootstrap Navbar component. All my current Navbar children are NavItem components.

I want the login button to be part of the collapsable (hamburger menu) part of the Navbar, but unlike the other NavItems, this button is not meant to be a link that will alter the URL path. When clicked, the login button will just render a React-Bootstrap Modal component.

How do I get the Login button to be a part of my Navbar?

My code...

```
<Navbar staticTop inverse collapseOnSelect>
   <Navbar.Header>
       <Navbar.Brand id="navbarBrand">
           <img id="logoImg" src="/images/bvLogo.svg" />
       </Navbar.Brand>
       <Navbar.Toggle />
   </Navbar.Header>
   <Navbar.Collapse>
       <Nav pullRight>
           <RouteNavItem className="headerLinks" eventKey={1} href="/">Home</RouteNavItem>
           <RouteNavItem className="headerLinks" eventKey={2} href="/shop">Shop</RouteNavItem>
           <RouteNavItem className="headerLinks" eventKey={3} href="/about">About</RouteNavItem>
           <RouteNavItem className="headerLinks" eventKey={4} href="/cart">Cart</RouteNavItem>
       </Nav>
   </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
<Button id="loginBtn" onClick={this.open}>Login</Button>
```

RouteNavItem is a custom component I wrote, but it doesn't have anything to do with the functionality of the Login button.

**** EDIT ****

This is a link to a picture of how I want the header of the site to look...
https://s3.amazonaws.com/tylermayberry/Screen+Shot+2017-10-09+at+3.17.34+PM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything inside `<Navbar.Collapse/>` component is going to be inside of the hamburger menu.

So you need to add your button inside the collapse component like this:

```
<Navbar.Collapse>
    <Nav pullRight>
         <RouteNavItem className="headerLinks" eventKey={1} href="/">Home</RouteNavItem>
         <RouteNavItem className="headerLinks" eventKey={2} href="/shop">Shop</RouteNavItem>
         <RouteNavItem className="headerLinks" eventKey={3} href="/about">About</RouteNavItem>
         <RouteNavItem className="headerLinks" eventKey={4} href="/cart">Cart</RouteNavItem>
     </Nav>
     <Navbar.Form pullRight> 
         <Button bsStyle="primary">Login</Button>
    </Navbar.Form>
</Navbar.Collapse>
```

NOTE: using [Navbar.Form](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navbars-form) for proper alignment

Comment: The login button stays to the left of the Navbar, even though it is being specified after the Nav and its RouteNavItem children. How can I get the login button to be to the right of the links?

Comment: @jtylerm Try adding ‘className=“pull-right”’ to the ‘Login’ button

Comment: it's still staying to the left

Comment: @jtylerm You also need to remove the `pullRight` attribute from your `NavBar`. Here is an example of how to do it. https://jsfiddle.net/jalissa/vhe8ohnk/2/

Comment: well, i'm trying to have the button just be part of the navbar and the navbar be to the right side of the page with a logo image to the left side of the page. if i take pullRight off the Nav with the links, then it'll render as a logo and the nav links to the left side and the login button to the right side. is there not a way to make the button just be part of the Nav with the links so that they're all on the right side and the logo on the left side?